# php - Gmail doesn't accept emails that contains links

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I am using PHPmailer to send emails that contain activation codes to the people who have signed up on my website. Everything worked fine with Yahoo! but not with Gmail.
There is no errors in my PHP script. Everything looked okay.
I tried to remove all the links from the email text and replaced it with random string like 'rrrrrrr' and it worked, I received the mail in my mailbox.
This only happens with Gmail. Does anyone knows how to overcome this problem?
Also, I am hosting my website on hostinger.com but i am currently testing PHPmailer on localhost using wampserver

EDIT: my website is http://www.pascal-tweaks.esy.es/ I don't think that it looks like a spam link.
I found my emails in the spam folder, but I must say that two days ago it was working fine with Gmail and I was receiving them in my mailbox. I thought maybe they recently decided to not trust links like that?
I still want another solution because I don't want my website's users to bother going to the spam folder :(

Here is my code, $email_sent is always true :

```
$toemail = $_SESSION['toemail'];
$nom = $_SESSION['name'];
$email_color = $_SESSION['email_color'];
$email_theme = $_SESSION['email_theme'];
$index = $_SESSION['index'];
$code = $_SESSION['code'];

$smtphost = 'smtp.topnet.tn';
$smtpport = 25;


$dom = 'http://www.mydomain.esy.es';

$from = 'mydomain@support.com';
$fromname = 'mywebsite';
$subj = 'signing in';
$greating = 'Thank you for registering!';
$htmlbody = 
    '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title>' . $greating . '</title>
        </head>
        <body style="margin:0;padding:10px 0;">
            <div style="width:450px;height:450px;max-height:450px;border:1px solid ' . $email_color . ';border-radius:260px;background-image:url(\'' . $dom . '/cssjs/theme' . $email_theme . '.jpg\');background-size:cover;box-shadow:0 0 22px 2px ' . $email_color . ';margin:30px auto;overflow:hidden;">
                <div style="height:78px;max-height:78px;width:350px;color:' . $email_color . ';margin:60px auto 54px auto;text-align:center;font-family:\'Cordia New\', \'Aparajita\';text-shadow:1px 1px 4px gray;">
                    <div style="font-size:52px;height:52px;max-height:52px;"><a style="text-decoration:none;color:' . $email_color . ';" href="' . $dom . '" target="_blank">My WebSite Name</a></div>
                    <div style="font-size:26px;height:26px;max-height:26px;">Welcome to my website!</div>
                </div>
                <div style="text-shadow:0 0 1px gray;background-image:url(\'' . $dom . '/cssjs/t_white.png\');width:429;height:238px;border-radius:8px 8px 260px 260px;padding:10px;font-family:\'Cordia New\', \'Aparajita\';">
                    <div style="margin:15px auto;font-size:22px;line-height:22px;text-align:center;width:400px;">' . $greating . ' <br/>' . $nom . ' !</div>
                    <div style="margin:15px auto;font-size:19px;line-height:19px;text-align:center;width:400px;">In order to activate your account, you must follow this link : <a href="' . $dom . '/activate.php?d=' . $index . '" target="_blank">' . $dom . '/activate_account</a><br/>Your activation code :<br/>' . $code . '</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>';
$altbody =  $greating . ' ' . $nom . ' !' . "\r\n" .
            'In order to activate your account, you must follow this link  :' . "\r\n" .
            'Activation link : ' . $dom . '/activate.php?d=' . $index . "\r\n" .
            'Activation code : ' . $code;

require_once ($webdir . '/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$activation_mail = new PHPMailer;

$activation_mail->isSMTP();
$activation_mail->Host = $smtphost;
$activation_mail->Port = $smtpport;

$activation_mail->From = $from;
$activation_mail->FromName = $fromname;
$activation_mail->SetFrom($from, $fromname);
$activation_mail->addAddress($toemail);
$activation_mail->addReplyTo($from, $fromname);
$activation_mail->isHTML(true);
$activation_mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$activation_mail->Subject = $subj;
$activation_mail->Body = $htmlbody;
$activation_mail->AltBody = $altbody;

if($activation_mail->send()){
    $email_sent = true;
}
else{
    $email_sent = false;
}
```

Comment: What does your link contain ? Any spam links ? Have you checked in spam folder if so ?

Comment: Do you really send via a remote host without authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Your website http://www.pascal-tweaks.esy.es/ is hosted on free domain provider..I think this is one of the reason for receiving mail in the spam folder..
2.) try this when you post your site on facebook wall or you message anybody it ll ask you about the security check or captcha..
So perhaps because of that gmail does not show link ..
thanks..

Comment: but i am pretty sure that it was working fine just two days ago

Comment: I check out your code ..I received an email on my email id (Not g mail )..i think it's taken as spam because of  free domain provider.